# Ansible lineinfile commented and non commented line

Tags: ansible

I have a file which contains two lines:

```
#Level menu
Level menu
```

I want to check the line `Level` has only `menu`. If other than this replace the line so I used the following parameters for the `lineinfile` task:

```
dest=/var/apache/test.conf
regexp="^\s*#*?\s*Level"
line="Level menu"
```

When I ran the playbook I got two lines in the file:

```
Level menu
Level menu
```

So a duplicate line has appeared.

**case1 :**

```
#Level menu
```

**case2:**

```
#Level menu
Level menu
```

**case3:**

```
Level submenu
```

In all the cases should come answer `Level menu`.

I want to check first without comment line if not there then check with comment line or is there any other solution?

Comment: You **cannot** merge two lines into a single one with `lineinfile` module.

Comment: No in second case is problem because, if i use regex `#*Level` first case and third case will be work but second case out put comes two duplicate line because lineinfile only see first line not consider second line.

Answer (score 3):

If I read your requirements correctly, you are looking for something as simple as:

```
- lineinfile:
    dest: /var/apache/test.conf
    regexp: ^Level
    line: Level menu

- lineinfile:
    dest: /var/apache/test.conf
    regexp: ^#Level
    state: absent
```

---

Example 1:

- Before:

  ```
  #Level menu
  Level menu
  ```
- After:

  ```
  Level menu
  ```

Example 2:

- Before:

  ```
  #Level menu
  Level menu and something else
  ```
- After:

  ```
  Level menu
  ```